# Proper layout solution - android

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

Hello I want a layout that looks like http://developer.android.com/images/training/layout-listitem.png instead of image view that is on the left I want a button on the right. But my button is right after text view not stick to the right. I was looking for other solutions but nothing helped me. Here's what I've got.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="12pt"
            android:id="@+id/view_to" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="8pt"
            android:id="@+id/view_what" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:text="@string/b_send"
            android:id="@+id/b_send" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use `RelativeLayout`.  Much more flexible for this kind of layout.

Comment: my button isnt stick on the right edge but right after longer textView

Comment: in editor it's fine but it occurs when i run the app. I should have mentioned it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `RelativeLayout`. Bind the `Button` to the right side of the layout using `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"`. The layout that holds the `TextViews` must have `android:layout_width="match_parent"` and `android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/<id-of-the-Button>"`, where  must be replaced with the `Button`'s id.

Comment: yes i have just figured it out :) android:layout_toLeftOf="id" worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

LinearLayout1 - android:layout_weight="3" (it will take approx. 75% space),

LinearLayout2 - android:layout_weight="1" (it will take approx. 25% space),

and for Button set layout_width and layout_height to "fill_parent" - this will make the button take all the space in LinearLayout2.

If you need the button take more or less space horizontally you can change layout_weight in LinearLayout1.

This is my xml-file example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="5dp">


<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="3">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#999999"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#777777"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView2" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">

<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ff6633"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Button"
    android:id="@+id/button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is result:

[image: LinearLayout]